# How to change a JSON string to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

It should be very easy, but I have used days to figure out, how to change a dynamic created JSON string of objects to an array.  What I want is this in javascript:

```
var col_model =[ { 'label': 'Name', 'name': 'Name', 'key': 'true', 'width': '75', 'hidden': 'false' }, { 'label': 'FirstName', 'name': 'FirstName' }];
```

It works perfectly in my model and the Chrome browser accept as [object, object, object].

But, when I create it dynamically, and then the Chrome browser does not accept it as an array of json objects. Example: I have this created first as a string:

```
var col_model = { 'label': 'Name', 'name': 'Name', 'key': 'true', 'width': '75', 'hidden': 'false' }, { 'label': 'FirstName', 'name': 'FirstName' };

col_model=[col_model];
```

But, it is not the same even when I add [] in the selcon dline. I have also tried to parse it like this but it does not work either:

```
col_model = $.parseJSON('[' + col_model + ']');
```

Comment: a string would be enclosed in `"` or `'`. What you have in the second example is simply a syntax error. If it actually is a string and you just couldn't copy and paste it here, try `col_model = "[" + col_model + "]";`

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried to enclose it in var col_model="{ 'label':' Name' ect ect. But it is the same result.

Comment: Also, key names and strings in a JSON string are wrapped within double quotes, this is not optional.

Comment: The first example works with single quotes. I have tried to change it to double quotes before, but no change in the result. I am really lost here.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Stringified array? In order to parse it? Why? `the browser does not accept it as an array of json objects` because it's not an array. It's not a string either, it's just some invalid syntax. I don't understand what you're trying to do. What's the input, and what's the expected output?

Comment: Your first example is a JS object, not JSON.

Comment: You should spend some time understanding how JSON and JS differ.

Comment: Hi Jeremy
I am trying to pass data to a JqGrid. I have followed all the examples they have and all works perfect. That is: as long I am hardcoding the lines, as in the jqGrid examples. But when I try to do the exact same thing with a dynamic variable, just without the array [] and add it to the next line, it all fails. I have checked the dynamic variable, and that is ok. It is like the browser does not understand it is multiple objects in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very clear what you are trying to achieve here. Assuming you want to convert an object array, available as a string, to actual array of objects, try the below.

Your object array as string

```
var col_model ="[ { 'label': 'Name', 'name': 'Name', 'key': 'true', 'width': '75', 'hidden': 'false' }, { 'label': 'FirstName', 'name': 'FirstName' }];"
```

Note the `"` at both ends

You can use an `eval` statement to convert ti back to object array

```
var newObjArray = eval(col_model)
```

Having said that, one must be careful in using `eval` as it is quite powerful and potentially dangerous at the same time. Please read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: WOW. That worked as a charm. I have never used eval before, because I thought it was dangerous somehow to use. But it worked. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Again, _dangerous_ depends on how you use it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your console browser, surely you are getting an error like unexpected string.

That's because :

```
    var col_model = { 'label': 'Name', 'name': 'Name', 'key': 'true', 'width': '75', 'hidden': 'false' }, { 'label': 'FirstName', 'name': 'FirstName' };
```

You cannot store two objects separated by a comma in a variable. Or is an Array of objects or is an single object , but what you've written is incorrect.

Then you can access to the object in the proper way an set its values and parse it.

I hope it may help you.